# Importing robovm-ios-bindings to eclipse

Tags: ios, eclipse, libgdx, admob, robovm

I am trying to import robovm-ios-bindings to eclipse, using this link:

https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings/tree/master/admob

I am following this tutorial to add ads to iOS using this tutorial:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx

And it says that "Once you have the robovm admob bindings go ahead and import that into your ide". However, when I try to import it to eclipse (import < Existing Projects into Workspace < Select root directory), and once I choose the file with robovm iOS bindings (robovm-ios-bindings-master), eclipse says "No projects are found to impot".

So how does one go about importing this into eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings/ are no longer supported. Use https://github.com/robovm/robovm-robopods

Use gradle to import into your IDE. See site above how to integrate.